# Proof that the SQL Server is not at fault for the timeout

Tags: sql-server, timeout

We have been experiencing (perceived) issues with the write performance of our MS SQL Server for some time. As I believe it might be on the client side, I am looking for evidence to refute the accusations against the SQL Server. Here is the situation: A NodeRed Flow collects data from a machine and writes it to an SQL Server in the end. If writing is not possible, the data is buffered in Redis until it can be written again. As mentioned, for some time now, the buffers have been filling up repeatedly, going from a normal workload of about 50 messages to over 1000 - 30000 messages. After several minutes (10 - 60), the buffers are emptied again. The only error message received is a timeout within 2 seconds. The writing node is more or less a black box for us.

What we have done so far: When the problem occurred, we set up monitoring of the buffers. Additionally, at the time of increasing buffers, we could look at the SQL Server and found nothing unusual in the Resource Monitor of the Windows Server... CPU, Disk, and Network were at a normal operating level. Only when the buffers were emptied, did we see a change on the SQL Server.

On the monitoring (Telegraf + Grafana) of the SQL Server, during that time, you can see a Write Latency of < 1 second on the database.

A restart of the SQL Server was also performed. However, this did not affect the full buffers; they neither increased nor decreased.

As the database manager, I am now seeking evidence that the SQL Server is not responsible for the timeout in the data flow. In addition to the option of comparing the monitoring, I would like to provide proof that during the time when the buffers are filling up, the client is not sending any requests to the SQL Server.

Are there any possibilities to achieve this with the existing resources?

Thank you and best regards, Martin

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, SQL Server doesn't timeout, by design. Only the calling client can issue a timeout. SQL Server will happily chug away for years on the same query, if the calling client doesn't issue a cancellation. The only exception I'm aware of to this is when the SQL Server instance makes a remote query call to another database instance. Then the local instance becomes the client, and SQL Server has properties that can be configured for how long before it times out waiting for the remote query (which can be set to infinite if needed, anyway). For more information, please see the docs on [Troubleshoot query time-out errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/troubleshoot-query-timeouts).

But I take it what you really mean is you're looking for a way to prove your SQL Server instance isn't the bottleneck causing the client to reach its timeout threshold which is then causing the client side to issue a timeout. If that's the case, then the following tools are helpful for tracing the database layer:

1. [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) - A good tool with a UI for tracing everything running on a SQL Server instance. It'll provide details such as the start and end time of a query and its duration. The trace can be filtered according to database, user, and other attributes as needed.
2. [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) - A very handy stored procedure for executing on demand and seeing what's running on the server in that very moment. It'll provide similar information regarding who ran the query, how long it's been running for so far, the database it's executing under, wait stats, blocking information, and more.
3. [First Responder Kit](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/) - A series of advanced tools that expand upon what `sp_WhoIsActive` provides, some of which are for troubleshooting server performance problems holistically.
4. [`sp_PressureDetector`](https://erikdarling.com/sp_pressuredetector/) - Another set of excellent tools specifically for holistically looking at potential resource contention issues with the server.
5. [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) - A similar tool to the Profiler, newer in age, and lighter in weight when profiling a server. But, to be honest, I personally find these a little harder to configure and gather information from and prefer the Profiler's UI for quickly getting started.
6. [`sp_HumanEvents`](https://erikdarling.com/sp_humanevents/) - As mentioned by Jonathan Fite, this is another tool that simplifies using Extended Events. It is written by Erik Darling who also created `sp_PressureDetector`.
7. [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16) - Enabling this will cause the database to log multiple metrics about the queries as they're executed within it. It can be used to look retroactively at how well or unwell certain queries are performing, and what the biggest bottlenecks are. It also offers the ability to force different execution plans to be used against the queries it captured which can be useful for stubborn regressed queries.

Comment: Erik Darling has made a stored procedure (sp_humanevents) that makes extended events easier (IMO) to setup.  Take a look. https://erikdarling.com/sp_humanevents/

Answer (score 1):

Is it a Query execution timeout or a connection timeout?

For query execution - SQL Server won't terminate a long-running query. It's the app that "runs out of patience" and sends an attention signal to abort the query (usually 30 seconds) when it doesn't get at least a partial result back. But it could also be aborted by a User of the app.

Two tools that I'd use for debugging timeouts are:

#### Query Store

- Easiest to set up
- Database-scoped
- Look into [sys.query_store_runtime_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-runtime-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) where `execution_type` = 3 (Aborted)
- Data is aggregated that you might lose some details

#### Extended Events (XE)

- Server-scoped
- You can add and filter on audit column like host_name, client_app_name, etc
- Monitor `rpc_completed` and `sql_batch_completed` where `result = Abort` (probably filter out SSMS queries)
- You can also use a free monitoring tool [DBA Dash](https://dbadash.com/) (not affiliated), which creates and reads from that XE for you (among other things)
- Here's a blog post about it - https://dbadash.com/docs/how-to/troubleshoot-timeout/

The main thing I'm usually interested in is if the query was running or waiting.

- Duration = 30 sec (or your threshold for a timeout), but CPU and logical reads are low => it was waiting.
- Duration and CPU = 30 sec => it was running but didn't finish
- Duration = 30 and CPU >= 30 => it was running in parallel but didn't finish